# How to update Gradle version to 7.3 in a Java project downloaded from GitHub with JDK 17 and avoid dependency issues?

Tags: java, gradle, version, project, java-14

I downloaded the project from the git hub to java, he has a gradle build version 6.3, and it needs to be run with the sdk version 14, but for my assignment at the university I need to run the project on version 17, how to raise the gradle version to 7.3 and not break the project
https://github.com/slamach/prog-labs/tree/master/prog-lab6 - link to the git from which I downloaded the project

I tried to change the version in gradle wrapper, but errors appeared during assembly, apparently the problem is in the dependencies, but I do not know what to do with them
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PAoBMxiXy77cMjkulIplKhuw0YXxsO48LMv94oW-jHw/edit - file with exception

Comment: "errors appeared". Um, yes.

Comment: What errors appeared?  And ... how come you need to download some random (archived) project from github to complete your assignment?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PAoBMxiXy77cMjkulIplKhuw0YXxsO48LMv94oW-jHw/edit

Comment: I expected to see them, but such a huge number is frightening

Comment: Please [edit] the question in order to add new information.

Comment: what exactly should I add to the question?

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful, without external links. Links can break, or linked content can change, making the question useless for others with similar problems. See also [ask].